Import arcpy in Python IDLE not working
I've installed ArcGIS Pro 3.4 (annual license for personal use) and Python IDLE 3.11.9. When I try to import arcpy in the IDLE I get the following error message:
import arcpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import arcpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'. 

Why can't my IDLE find arcpy?
I tried in Visual Studio Code and got the same result.

I suggest you use the Python IDLE interpreter that is bundled with ArcGIS Pro Python (arcgispro-py3).  At a minimum, another install of Python IDLE would have to be configured to point to the Pro Python interpreter, but I am not sure it would work 100% correctly.  Although Esri isn't providing a shortcut for IDLE anymore with a Pro install, it still exists.  You can run it multiple ways, they even have a batch file to launch it:  C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat

Agreed, you will need to know the path to ArcGIS Pro's installation of Python to be able to select it as an interpreter. I use Arcpy in Visual Studio code (and yes, it's a pain you can't just import out of the box), but I have to switch to selecting Esri's specific installation of Python by choosing a new interpreter in the command box.

Many thanks, using that batch file I can open script files and arcpy is recognized without problems! Basically I had ptyhon already installed into another directory, I believe that's why there is the problem if I launch python IDLE from the usual path. If I totally uninstall Python and re-install it, which should be the correct path where to install it? Can you please let me know?

You can have multiple versions of Python installed and only the ESRI version of Python will have arcpy.  Here is some help configuring other Python IDEs to work with the ESRI version of Python https://resources.esri.ca/getting-technical/configure-your-python-ide-to-work-with-arcmap-and-arcgis-pro-s-arcpy
